# ICICI: Redeem Mutual Fund SIPs through net banking

Tags: india, mutual-funds, online-banking

I invested in mutual fund through ICICI net banking. After 7 SIPs, I stopped transaction for that fund, but did not get any money back in my bank account. Can someone please guide how to redeem the Stopped SIPs through ICICI net banking?

Answer (score 1):

You have used your ICICI bank account to contribute amount towards your SIP. To  withdraw funds you need to raise request to respective fund house.

Since, you have not mentioned the fund house where you invested, I would suggest general approach.

Go to the fund house.Example [ICICI MF](https://www.icicipruamc.com/) since you have mentioned ICICI Bank or google your fund house details.

Once you reach the site of your fund house. You can create your account using PAN and other basic details. Once you login, you can raise redemption request funds will reflect into your account in 2-4 working days.

My Advice: Since you have started investment 7 months back, it would be wise to wait for some time since most of funds have -ve returns since the market is on the downside. Instead, you should try to put in more money.

**Edit 1**
Edited Links for User creation

- [IDFC Asset Management Company](https://mfonline.idfcmf.com/IDFCMOB/MOBUserCreation.aspx)
- [Aditya Birla AMC](https://mf.adityabirlacapital.com/Pages/Secured/Individual/OneABC/Login.aspx)

Comment: I invested in "Aditya Birla SL Medium Term-Growth", "IDFC Bond Fund-Medium Term Plan - Growth". Can you please provide links for their fund house.

Comment: @CodeZila have posted links for user creation, after sharing basic details like pan,email you can register and then you can login into your account